# Can we give the integer value of the secondary camera in setVideoSource?

Tags: android, android-camera

I wanted to record videos in my application using secondary camera available on the device. I am using the following code to get the int value of the secondary camera:

```
    int mNumberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
    int mSecondaryCamera;
    for(int i=0;i<mNumberOfCameras;i++)
    {
         Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
         if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
             mSecondaryCamera=i;
             break;
         }
    }
```

I am using *MediaRecorder.setVideoSource(mSecondaryCamera);* to set the video source to the secondary camera but its still initiating the primary camera..
Can anyone help me with this by providing a sample code or a solution to this problem?

Thanks